# How do we know what "animal" words are referring to in Hebrew?

Tags: genesis, hebrew, definition, plants-and-animals

Other than context, is there any way to determine what animals words like מִקְנֶה and בְּהֵמָה are referring to?  (For example, are the meanings of these words given in dictionaries like BDB determined by comparing with other Hebrew literature or strictly from scriptural references?)

For example, BDB tells us that מִקְנֶה can refer to all kinds of commodity animals including horses and camels and asses, but then in definition 2 it says specifically cows, sheep, and goats in flocks and herds.  But how do we know some of these passages aren't referring to groups of horses?  Is it entirely an assumption based on historic-anthropologic knowledge of practices?

+1 bonus if you can recommend an article with a detailed discussion of animal words in the OT.

Comment: The simple answer is BOTH - Hebrew and Greek lexicons are based on word usage in both the Bible and the literature of the time surround the area.